# How to get current active instance of jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have multiple datepicker controls on single page binded to input controls.
When I click on any of the input control datepicker control linked to that input gets visible.

Now I want to get input for which the current instance of datepicker is being shown on another JS events.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try using the `$.datepicker._getInst(target)` method to get any specific datepicker on your page.   You just have to pass in a target element, which you can do so by just passing the id using document.getElementById **(don't use JQuery** or it will return undefined).

So like so:

```
var id = document.getElementById('someId'); 
//replace someId with the id of the datepicker currently visible.  
var inst = window.$.datepicker._getInst(id);
```

This is especially helpful if you are trying  to get the current instance of a datepicker that's an inline element (not attached to an input).

Comment: I have attached datepicker to some HTML textboxes using CSS class name & `onSelect` event handler I need to know the selector class name on which current `onSelect` happened.. the elements have 2 other classes applied other then the one I am using to attach datepicker

Comment: Thanks for this!  You can actually use jquery but use index [0] to get the actual DOM element.  `var elem = jQuery('#someId'); var inst = jQuery.datepicker._getInst(elem[0]);`