# How can i add text with date in date picker(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date

I want to add some text with the date of date picker as shown in below image in green box with date. Please help me this.

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="txtdatepicker" />
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtdatepicker").datepicker();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, did you miss any image to attach?

Comment: sorry i have added now. thank you

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui datepicker?

Comment: yes i'm using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which way to add text to jquery ui datepicker cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959709/which-way-to-add-text-to-jquery-ui-datepicker-cell)

Comment: I think I am missing something, how are you getting this popup? Default popup is something different.

Comment: i have increase the width of popup